# UpdatePanel AsyncPostbackTrigger not firing

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, updatepanel

I've got a little problem, any help is appreciated.

Situation looks like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_Panel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSwitch" runat="server" Width="250px" AutoPostback="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSwitch_SelectedIndexChanged">

            <asp:ListItem Value="continent" Text="Continent"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="region" Text="Region"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="country" Text="Country"></asp:ListItem>

        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_Switch" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                // Some content
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlSwitch" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When *ddlSwitch* selected index change I want to update content inside *UP_Switch*, but `SelectedIndexChanged` event doesn't seem to fire. What am I doing wrong?

***Thanks in advance!***

Comment: Could you please add code for `SelectedIndexChanged` in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested your code and seems to be working with some test modifications: ASPX

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_Panel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSwitch" runat="server" Width="250px" AutoPostback="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSwitch_SelectedIndexChanged">

            <asp:ListItem Value="continent" Text="Continent"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="region" Text="Region"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="country" Text="Country"></asp:ListItem>

        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_Switch" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="litUpSwitch" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlSwitch" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind for `ddlSwitch_SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
protected void ddlSwitch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    litUpSwitch.Text = "DDL Switch go activated";
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: When I change item in DropDownList in debug mode, selected index changed event is never reached :(

Comment: Have you checked console for any underlying errors?

Comment: Well, I didn't until you reminded me.. my master page from whom I inherited already had <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> included and I included it in this page once again so it caused underlying problems. Thanks for your help and time, I can only give you my thanks with points, hopefully it's enough, you saved me :)